# Can you set the selected item in a ComboBox from a viewmodel via a binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

Why isn't my `ComboBox` updating from the viewmodel? My goal was to use the `ComboBox` as a trigger for running a query. A user selects a query and the screen updates. Meanwhile, the `ComboBox` should reset itself to the "Select a filter..." item. But after the selection, it is staying on the item selected by the user.

**ViewModel Code**

```
public class FilterManagerViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
  private CBFilterDefinition _noSelectionFilter = new CBFilterDefinition() { FilterName = "Select a filter...", FilterDefinitionId = -1 };

  public FilterManagerViewModel()
  {
    PopulateFilterDefinitionList();
  }

  public List<CBFilterDefinition> FilterDefinitions { get; private set; }

  private void PopulateFilterDefinitionList()
  {
    FilterDefinitions = GetFilterDefinitions(_firmId, _screenId, CBBusinessLayer.UserId).OrderBy(x => x.FilterName).ToList();
    FilterDefinitions.Insert(0, new CBFilterDefinition() { FilterName = "<Ad Hoc Filter...>", FilterDefinitionId = 0 });
    FilterDefinitions.Insert(0, _noSelectionFilter);

    OnPropertyChanged("FilterDefinitions");

    SelectedFilterDefinition = _noSelectionFilter;
  }

  public CBFilterDefinition SelectedFilterDefinition
  {
    get { return _noSelectionFilter; }
    set
    {
      if (value != null)
      {
        if (value.FilterDefinitionId == 0)
        {
          // Do some Ad Hoc filtery stuff, here.
        }
        else if (value.FilterDefinitionId > 0)
        {
          //Do some pre-defined filtery stuff, here.
        }
      }

      OnPropertyChanged("SelectedFilterDefinition");
    }
  }
}
```

**ComboBox XAML**

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FilterDefinitions}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFilterDefinition}"
          DisplayMemberPath="FilterName" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left" AlternationCount="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
```

It seem pretty simple, to me. But maybe my assumption that I should be able to set the selected item via the binding is not correct. (I did try setting the binding mode to TwoWay, but that didn't make a difference)

For good measure, I verified, through the debugger, that all object references point to the same instance of `_noSelectionFilter`. But there is only ever one instance of that item, so I'm not sure how it could be a reference issue, anyway. Do I have to bind to `SelectedIndex`? The `ComboBox` initializes, properly, so it seems the initial setting works.

The `SelectedFilterDefinition` getter is being called after the `OnPropertyChanged` call and it's returning the one and only instance of `_noSelectionFilter`.

What am I missing?

Comment: You could try adding updatesourcetrigger `SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFilterDefinition, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"` (and maybe removing DisplayMemberPath)

Comment: A ComboBox that immediately resets itself after the user has selected an item is horrible. I would think it's broken. Choose a different approach, e.g. select an action in the ComboBox, then press a Button to execute the action, *then* reset the ComboBox.

Comment: get { return _noSelectionFilter; }??? In `SelectedFilterDefinition` property you return always `_noSelectionFilter`. I'm agree with Clemens - it's poor usability.